# Why does the new android application open in the current activity?

Tags: android

The application support deeplinks.

**Logic of work:**

1. First, SplashActivity opens, where everything is loaded depending on
   the link.
2. Next, the data is transferred to MainActivity. MainActivity processes the received data and, depending on the type of data,
   opens the desired fragment, displaying the result.

**Problem.** When I open links via telegram, `SplashActivity` is first launched, and then `MainActivity` is opened. But `MainActivity` does not open the desired fragment. This is because there are no data in `getIntent().GetExtras()`.
But! If you click on the back system button, my application will close and telegram will open again (the telegram icon is visible in the list of applications). But instead of a telegram, the desired fragment of my application (which was not opened in `MainActivity`) will be opened.

**What could be causing this?**

**In `SplashActivity()`, after processing deeplink, I load data for it:**

```
private void openTagBySlug(String slug) {
        String url = String.format(DataParser.getJSONURL(DataParser.TAG_BY_SLUG), slug);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Type itemsListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Tag>>() {}.getType();
                        ArrayList<Tag> posts = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), itemsListType);
                        if (posts.size() != 0)
                        {
                            intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class); //todo fix it
                            intent.putExtra("deeplink", posts.get(0));
                        }
                        loadInter(0);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

**In loadInter(), load ads. After all, this method is called:**

```
private void startMainActivity() {
                if (intent == null)
                    intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
```

**Method onCreate() in the MainActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppAd.disableSplash();
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_content);
        appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
                        .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                        .build();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(
                toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            if (bundle.containsKey("deeplink")) {
                Object object = bundle.getSerializable("deeplink");
                Bundle data = new Bundle();
                if (object instanceof Post) {
                    data.putSerializable("post", (Post)bundle.getSerializable("deeplink"));
                    Navigation.findNavController(findViewById(R.id.main_content)).navigate(R.id.postFragment, data);
                } else if (object instanceof Category) {
                    data.putSerializable("category", bundle.getSerializable("deeplink"));
                    Navigation.findNavController(findViewById(R.id.main_content)).navigate(R.id.categoryFragment, data);
                } else if (object instanceof Tag) {
                    data.putSerializable("tag", bundle.getSerializable("deeplink"));
                    Navigation.findNavController(findViewById(R.id.main_content)).navigate(R.id.categoryFragment, data);
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: what do you want it to happen? your desired fragment not opening is the issue?

Comment: The desired fragment is opened, but in activity with telegram. On top of this activity, my application with MainActivity still opens, which overlaps the desired activity.

I want to have one of these:
1. My fragment was opened not in telegram, but in my application.
2. My fragment was opened in telegram, but my application did not block it.

Comment: I did not understand your second part. If you want to have only one activity you can call finish() for the previous activity during navigation

Comment: When I click on the link in the telegram, the application launches in the telegram window. And if you open the list of programs, you can see the telegram icon above my application. But at the same time, another screen opens in a new window with my application, which overlaps the screen.

Comment: This problem only occurs when my applications are running.

Comment: I think the problem is this: I am launching a new activity as follows. First I close the current activity, and then I open a new one.
In general: 1. I close the activity (which opened in a telegram). 2. I have my application open, which worked in the background. 3. The desired activity opens on the screen with telegram. But this screen was blocked on the second step.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this: I am launching a new activity as follows. First I close the current activity, and then I open a new one.

In general: 
1. I close the activity (which opened in a telegram). 
2. I have my application open, which worked in the background. 
3. The desired activity opens on the screen with telegram. But this screen was blocked on the second step

**Solution**: swap the last 2 lines. In this case, the screen will not be blocked by the background application

```
private void startMainActivity() {
        if (intent == null)
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```